# Dependant dropdown list

Tags: 7

I have 2 fields, *state* and *city*. I would like to change the *city* field when I select the *state* field.
I tried to use "hs_nodereference", but this module shows the *state* and *city* fields as follows.

```
statename: statelist
cityname: statelist  citylist
```

I want them to be shown as follows.

```
statename: statelist
cityname:  citylist
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Make a vocabulary with states at zero level and cities at deepest level for each state. Then install [hierarchical_select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

Enjoy :)

Comment: i used hs_nodereference but it was not not good for me. i tested hierarchical_select but i couldnt use it in taxonomy. is there any tutorial or video? thank u

Comment: look at http://www.mefeedia.com/watch/34006460

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a view with the display that'd you like (i.e. a view that is formatted so just `citylist` appears) then reference the view from the custom field. also it's possible that the view may need to have the same name as your reference field

to reference a view, under content types > fields > select the field you want  > configure

I'm actually using "Node reference views" module so maybe this advice is for that

Comment: thank you but problem is in CCK not view.  statename(label) : statelist (drop down to select)
cityname(label):  citylist (drop down to select)